# Sort entities by count of *-to-Many association in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, many-to-many

I'm developing a REST API (blog) using Spring Boot running with MySQL database.

Simply, I need to sort `Article` by the number of likes it has. The information about number of likes is stored in `article_likes` table which acts like association between `Article` and `User` (who liked the article).

```
@Entity
class Article {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "article_likes",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "article_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    Set<User> likedBy = new HashSet<>();

    @Column(name = "created")
    @CreationTimeStamp
    LocalDateTime added;
}
```

I'm having a service which returns a `Page` of `Article` for given `Pageable` (comes from frontend):

```
Page<Article> getArticles(Pageable pageable);
```

In frontend, when I'm showing list/page of articles, I'm using following call to get the last (newest) 5 articles.

```
localhost:8080/api/articles?size=5&sort=added,desc
```

I want to do the same with but with number of likes, something like this:

```
localhost:8080/api/articles?size=5&sort=likedBy,desc
```

I've tried following variations without the success.

```
sort=likedBy.size
sort=likedBy.count
sort=likedBy.length
```

with following error:

```
No property * found for type User! Traversed path: Article.likedBy.",
```

Is something like this possible? If not, is there a way to store just the read-only count of likes in `Article` (as attribute) instead? Because in this particular situation its not important who liked it, but only the count.

```
class Article {

    @Transient
    @ManyToMany
    ???
    long likes;
}
```